# Seperate elements in d3.js. Is there an array needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

i got a little question about d3.js. On this example i can click on a node, it checks, if the array "a" i created before, got the element "element1" and if yes, it turns the stroke-width of the links between the nodes bigger into 22px and the others into 3px.

Now, here is my problem. I want now manipulate only these new seperated thin ones with stroke-width of 3px.
How can i now get access to only these ones? Should i store them in an extra-array?

For example, i could create a new button and if i click on it, it will turn only these links with the size of 3px into green, but don't touch the other ones.

```
on("click", function(d, i){
    links.style("stroke-width", function(d){
                   return a.includes(d.element1) ? "22px" : "3px"; 
                });........
```

Comment: Really hard to answer this question without a concrete example.  What rule determines if a line should change to the new size?

Comment: Nope, still no idea what you are asking.  Let me phrase it like this.  You have a collection of `links` which are lines.  Now you want some part of this collection to increase it's `stroke-width` to `22px`.  How do you know which part of that collection to change?

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks for your patience. I got a force diagram in D3.js, that means links and nodes. Now, i can click on 2 nodes and highlight all links between those 2 nodes by increasing the `stroke-witdth` to `22px`. That is what the code `return a.includes(d.element1)` means.  The rest of the links, which are not between those 2 nodes i clicked at the beginning, got a thin `stroke-width` of `3px`. That is why i created that `var element1` in the post above. With it's help, i am able to store the elements. And now, i want to get access ONLY to the links with the `stroke-width` of `3px`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I might understand now.  The problem you are having with @EricGuan's solution is that he's selecting by the **attribute** stroke-width while you are using the **style** stroke width.  I think your best bet is a [.filter](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_filter):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script>
      
      var svg = d3.select('body')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('width','500px')
        .attr('height', '500px');
        
      var data = d3.range(10);
      
      var links = svg.selectAll('.link')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d', function(d){
          return "M0," + (d * 50 + 3) + "L500," + (d * 50 + 3);
        })
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", function(d){
          return Math.random() > 0.5 ? '10px' : '3px';
        });
    
      links.filter(function(d){
        return this.style.strokeWidth === '3px';
      })
      .transition()
      .duration(2000)
      .style('stroke-width', '23px');
      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow, this looks right to me. That is what i was looking for! But one question. You are you using `.style("stroke-width"` to define the styles. and then you seperate the `3px`ones with `return this.style.strokeWidth === '3px'` What i do not understand is: Why is that working? Because you are using a different writings. One time you write `stroke-width` and the other time later you are using `strokeWidth`. I just wonder, why it is working and why it is no error?

Comment: ok, i just tried to change it into `this.style.stroke-width === '3px'` and it is not working, because it says "width" is not defined

Comment: @DerickKolln: `this.style.strokeWidth === '3px'`, the `-` syntax in css is invalid in `javascript` and should be converted to `pascalCase`.

Comment: oh, thanks. That means  `font-size ` becomes  `fontSize`?

Comment: Hey Mark, can i ask you one more question? I am able to click on 2 nodes and highlight the links between them. All the other links for example i am able to seperate now. I created a button to click on and with the help of the filter() function i can put a opacity on them. That means the highlighted links are full watchable, and the other links all have opacity on it, AFTER I CLICKED ON THAT BUTTON. But when i click on 2 new nodes and highlight a new path between them, the opacity settings from the previous selection and path stays and won't change. Can you help me how to manage that problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can select elements by attribute.

```
d3.selectAll('line[stroke-width="3px"]')
```

Comment: Is this something like transition.filter()?